# Props dont get passed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

Im trying to make an emoji search app with react just for practice,I have three components, the first one is 'APP' and then an 'SearchBar' component that renders a search bar and also renders the third component which is 'EmojiContainer' that's supposed to display the emojis based on the props passed to it from the 'SearchBar' component.In the 'SearchBar' component i have 'emojiDescriptions' object, which has the emoji icons as keys and the descriptions of each emoji as values . Example :

```
'': ['happy', 'smiley', 'smiling', 'smile', 'laugh', 'laughing', 'positive emotion', 'every emoji', '2']
```

, and the process by which the emojis are filtered based on the search bar input is already solved, the problem is in the 'EmojiContainer' component , when i start the app by 'npm start' the first time all , the emojies get displayed correctly , but the page does not load completely, but once i refresh it the emojies disappear and even when i type something in the search bar i get no emoji displayed,the same thing happens when i modify something
in the 'EmojiContainer', all the emojies get displayed but the page does not load completely, but once i refresh it the emojies disappear.
That's the weirdest problem i've ever encountered.
this is the code for the 'SearchBar' component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import EmojiContainer from '../emoji-container/emojiContainer';
import { BeakerIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid';
import './searchBar.scss'
export default function SearchBar() {
    const [content, setContent] = useState('');
    const [emojiIcons] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        for (let i = 0; i < emotions.length; i++) {
            emojiIcons.push(Object.keys(emojiDescriptions)[parseInt(emotions[i].slice(-1))])
        }
    });

    // let emojiIcons = [];
    let emojiDescriptions = {
        '': ['happy', 'positive emotion', 'smile', 'smiling', 'every emoji', '0'],
        '': ['happy', 'smiley', 'smiling', 'positive emotion', 'every emoji', '1'],
        '': ['happy', 'smiley', 'smiling', 'smile', 'laugh', 'laughing', 'positive emotion', 'every emoji', '2'],
        '': ['happy', 'smiley', 'smiling', 'smile', 'laugh', 'laughing', 'positive emotion', 'every emoji', '3'],
        '': ['happy', 'smiley', 'positive emotion', 'smile', 'every emoji', '4'],
        '': ['smile', 'smiling', 'every emoji', '5'],
        '': ['smile', 'smiling', 'upside down face', 'every emoji', '6'],
        '': ['wink', 'winky face', 'every emoji', '7'],
        '': ['naughty face', 'laugh', 'laughing', 'every emoji', '8'],
        '': ['happy', 'positive emotion', 'smile', 'smiling', 'every emoji', '9'],
        '': ['happy', 'smiley', 'smiling', 'positive emotion', 'every emoji', '10'],
        '': ['happy', 'smiley', 'smiling', 'smile', 'laugh', 'laughing', 'positive emotion', 'every emoji', '11'],
        '': ['happy', 'smiley', 'smiling', 'smile', 'humble', 'every emoji', '12'],
        '': ['kiss', 'affection', 'every emoji', '13'],
        '': ['kiss', 'affection', 'every emoji', '14'],
        '': ['innocent', 'innocense', 'every emoji', '15'],
        '': ['heart eyes', 'love', 'affection', 'cat', 'every emoji', '16'],
        '': ['heart eyes', 'love', 'affection', 'every emoji', '17'],
        '': ['angry', 'angry face', 'every emoji', '18'],
        '': ['angry', 'angry face', 'devil', 'devil face', 'every emoji', '19'],
        '': ['monster', 'angry monster', 'angry', 'every emoji', '20'],
        '': ['monster', 'every emoji', '21'],
        '': ['skull', 'every emoji', '22'],
        '': ['alien', 'every emoji', '23'],
        '': ['ghost', 'every emoji', '24'],
        '': ['robot', 'every emoji', '25'],
        '': ['poop', 'eww', 'gross', 'every emoji', '26'],
        '': ['sleep', 'sleepy', 'sleepy face', 'every emoji', '27'],
        '': ['sleep', 'sleepy', 'every emoji', '28'],
        '': ['truck', 'every emoji', '29'],
        '': ['money', 'money eyes', 'every emoji', '30'],
        '': ['shoked', 'every emoji', '31']
    };
    let emotions=Object.values(emojiDescriptions).filter((emo) => emo.find((word) => word.includes(content)));
    return (
        <div className='search-bar-container'>
            <div className="title">
                <BeakerIcon />
                Emoji Search
            </div>
            <input type="text" className="search-bar" placeholder='Search for an emoji!' onChange={(e) => setContent(e.target.value)} value={content} />
            <EmojiContainer emojis={emojiIcons} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

and this is the code for the 'EmojiContainer' component:

```
import React from 'react'
import './emojiContainer.scss';
export default function EmojiContainer(props) {
    console.log(props.emojis)
    let emojiList = props.emojis.map((emo,ind)=>
        <li  className='emoji' key={ind}>{emo}</li>
    );
    return (
        <ul className='emoji-container'>
            {emojiList}
        </ul>

    )
}
```

this is the link to the project so you can go through the files : https://github.com/Marouane328/Emoji-search-with-react/tree/master/emoji-search

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: You're changing a state array directly by pushing to it; you're not supposed to do that.

Comment: Like @ChrisG mentioned, you need a setter here `const [emojiIcons] = useState([])`.  It should be `const [emojiIcons, setEmojiIcons] = useState([])` and `setEmojiIcons` should be used instead of changing the `emojiIcons` state directly like you're doing.

Comment: Here's a fixed version: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-hertz-8lefg?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

There are some things in your code that are mutating the existing state which in React is something you should not do, I would so some changes in your code as well, in order to initialize variables again in every re render.

First thing I would do is to move the **emojiDescriptions** variable outside of the component (maybe a constants file or something like that) just make sure is not inside the component since that is a variable that won't change.

Second, your useEffect should be the one handling all the logic of filtering the emojis whenever the content of the search bar changes, you can achieve that adding the content, as a dependency in the dependency array argument of the useEffect hook like this:

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
   // Logic here
 }, [content]);
```

That means that when the input is changed the effect will be run with al the logic inside.

Third is to move your emotions variable inside the useEffect since that should not be run in outside of it, and in order to prevent mutability, don't use push in the emojiIcons array, also with Object.entries you can do a one liner instead of having to do a for each after filtering the emojis.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const emojis = Object.entries(emojiDescriptions)
    .filter(([_key, value]) => value.find((word) => word.includes(content)))
    .map(([key]) => key);

  setEmojiIcons(emojis);
}, [content]);
```

And now you should be able to filter and if you refresh the page everything should be back to normal and you should be able to see all the emojis.

I have a sandbox here with the working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-archimedes-6i55k